# Espresso: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 2 intents

Tags: android, android-espresso

I know there are few similar questions already asked here, however no answer solved my problem.

I am trying to test if my **MainActivity** is starting from **SplashActivity** after 2 seconds or not.

Here is my test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class SplashActivityTest {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = ActivityScenarioRule(SplashActivity::class.java)
    private val splashScreenWaitingTime = 2000L

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        Intents.init()
    }

    @After
    fun teardown() {
        Intents.release()
    }

    @Test
    fun navigateToMainScreenAfter2Secs() {
        val idlingRes = ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(splashScreenWaitingTime)
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(idlingRes)
        intended(hasComponent(MainActivity::class.java.name))
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(idlingRes)
    }
}
```

The above test works absolutely fine. But the problem comes if I add some other test and that test runs before the above mentioned test. For example, let's say I have added another empty test as mentioned below:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    // No code here
}
```

Since all test cases runs independently, if **test()** runs before **navigateToMainScreenAfter2Secs()**, then I am getting the error: `androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 2 intents.`

I know using `times(2)` makes the trick. But not sure why? Why do the intents matched twice even if I add an empty test case?

If you are suspecting my production code might have some issue, then here is the production code:

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Thread(Runnable {
            Thread.sleep(2000)
            runOnUiThread {
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }).start()
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? What causes the intent fire twice even though I release the Intents for every test cases?